# how to modify this regular expression to exclude the 3rd type of result

Tags: regex

Here are three patterns which may occur in the search string:

```
<a href=".+?" target="_blank" id="">.+?</a>
<a href=".+?" target="_blank" id=""><font color=green>.+?</font></a>
<a href=".+?" target="_blank" id=""><b><font color=green>.+?</font></b></a>
```

The expression I wrote matches all of the above:

```
<a href="(.+?)" target="_blank" id="">(<font color=.+?>)?(.+?)(</font>)?</a>
```

How can I write a regular expression to match only the first and the second string, the third one should be excluded in the result.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML/XML, use a DOM parser library.

Comment: Look up "negative lookbehind" at regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you [should avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1204143) parsing (X)HTML with regex.

In your case, you may be able to avoid matching tags in the contained text using an expression like

```
<a href="(.+?)" target="_blank" id="">(<font color=.+?>)?([^<]*?)(</font>)?</a>
```

Note that this will ignore *all* tags in the `<a>` content.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! anyway, i'm just writing a piece of code doing very simple work, it's annoying to find a DOM parser lib and install it.

Comment: That's what everyone says until the regexes start piling up... :)